# Stop 2nd TAB from undoing indenting

Tags: indentation

I noticed something that might be a feature, but I find it rather annoying. Say I have a piece of code:

```
some_function = (x, y) ->
  z()
```

and I wish to add a new function call one indentation level deeper than the `z()`. To illustrate it I will use indenting.

```
some_function = (x, y) ->
  z()
foo()
```

This is with no indentation

```
some_function = (x, y) ->
  z()
->foo()
```

Pressing tab once, places two spaces in front of `foo()`

```
some_function = (x, y) ->
  z()
foo()
```

Pressing tab again does not do the expected behavior of adding two additional spaces. Instead, it de-indents back to the beginning.

Is there a way to override this?

*EDIT:*

Here's my relevant configuration stuff

```
(custom-set-variables
   '(coffee-tab-width 2)
   '(coffee-indent-like-python t)
)


(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 2)
(setq tab-always-indent t)
(electric-indent-mode 1)
```

Comment: What major mode are you using?

Comment: @nanny I have seen this behavior in coffee mode (coffeescript) but I'm sure it occurs elsewhere

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. Pressing TAB repeatedly cycles between 0, 1, and 2 indent levels, as I expect in a indentation-significant language like coffeescript. Can you share any relevant configuration? Indentation settings, what function TAB is bound to, etc.

Comment: @nanny added anything I have that touches indentation. It seems tabbing only goes up to the level of the thing above it. You can't go passed it by pressing tab.

Comment: I don't have any experience with coffeescript, but the same thing happens in Python mode, and with good reason. It seems like the behaviour you are describing is simply cycling between valid indentation levels. At least in python, nesting your call to `foo()` under `z()` would cause an IndentationError because you are using an unexpected indent? Could you confirm whether or not you are trying to indent `foo()` further than `z()`?

Comment: @elethan I am trying to indent `foo()` farther than `z()` in this case. This behavior is most noticeable when trying to nest calls on an object.

Comment: I assume that is valid indentation in coffeescript in that case? If it is valid, it might have something to do with `coffee-indent-like-python`, because this is not valid indentation for Python

Comment: @elethan I dont think so. `coffee-indent-like-python` just makes it so it automagically indents the next line for you properly based on what you just typed above (like a function or whatever)

Comment: @Steve You "don't think so"? Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have seen with the languages that I work in, emacs major modes for programming languages will often define their own functions to indent code properly for that language. To see some of these functions you can do `C-h f` type `coffee-indent-` and then tab to see the list of different indentation functions that `coffee-mode` provides, and pick one to read it's documentation. I looked through the source code of `coffee-mode.el` and I don't really understand enough elisp to comment on exactly how what setting `coffee-indent-like-python-mode` to `t` will do exactly, but my assumtion from the variable name and from the behaviour it achieves as described in my tests below, is that it causes the `coffee-mode` indentation commands to behave like `python-mode` indentation commands (i.e., causes them to behave exactly as you are describing above).

From tests that I ran in a few scratch buffers, I think that the problem is indeed caused by the variable `coffee-indent-like-python-mode`.
Here are the steps that I took to reproduce and then fix your problem (at least in my version of emacs). (Also note that my tabs are bigger than yours, but that shouldn't make a difference. I have enabled `whitespace-mode` for these screenshots so that it is clear that each indent is a single tab)

1. Opened a scratch buffer and set it to `coffee-mode` with `M-x coffee-mode`.
2. Pasted in this code with `z()` and `foo()` at the same indentation level:

[image]

3. Hit tab on the line with `z()` indenting it on level

[image]

4. Hit tab on the line with `foo()` indenting it to the same level as `z()`

[image]

5. Hit tab again on the line with `foo()` nesting it one level below `z()`

[image]

If I understand your question correctly, this is the behaviour you are looking for, right? Pressing tab again on the line with `foo()` will bring it back to to the first level, subsiquent tabs will cycle through levels one, two, and three in this case.

6. I opened a new scratch buffer in `lisp-interaction-mode`, entered the code `(setq coffee-indent-like-python-mode t)` (notice the `mode` at the end of the variable name which is missing from your sample configuration), and evaluated that code with the point after the last paren with `C-x C-e`. Then I returned to my `coffee-mode` buffer and tried indenting again with tab. As expected it indents "like python-mode", i.e., it will not indent `foo()` past `z()`, because this kind of indentation is invalid in Python.
7. I went back to my lisp buffer, changed the `t` to `nil`, i.e., `(setq coffee-indent-like-python-mode nil)`, evaluated that, and back in my `coffee-mode` buffer I can indent `foo()` past `z()` again.

Please try these experiments, or simply try removing the reference to `coffee-indent-like-python-mode` in your config (or set it to `nil`) to see if it works. Let me know if you have other questions or need to do more troubleshooting.

Comment: +1, this is a very generous answer that could've easily just been a comment similar to the one I left on the question. Though it's overly-generous if you ask me: the problem was immediately clear after op edited-in his settings. It took me less than a minute to install coffee-mode and figure it out, I assume you figured it out very quickly as well.

Comment: @nanny From the conversation in comments above, it seemed like I was not understanding the OP or the OP was not understanding me, so I did as you said, installing coffee-mode to see for myself, and decided to post a detailed answer to try to make the cause of the problem and the solution very clear for the OP and for future users who may have a similar question. I am also somewhat sympathetic to the OP because I had similar indentation-related confusion when I first started using emacs - it often works in a way that makes sense to me now, but that is different from other editors and IDEs

Comment: This is a great answer. Wow. Thank you.